# Translation of はじめとする

Tags: translation

I know the meaning of this phrase I believe, it is used to give the most common or important example when you are abbreviating a list. I can't come up with anything that sounds really good as a translation.

> Policy A, Policy B をはじめとする guidelines on the topic of X.

What I have at the moment is

> Guidelines on the topic of X including Policy A and Policy B.

Comment: "with A and B being the first (two) on the list" とか "with A and B at the head of the list" とか "including, most importantly, A and B" とかだと変ですかね・・

Answer (score 5):

http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E3%82%92%E3%81%AF%E3%81%98%E3%82%81%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%22

```
           Policy A, Policy B ... をはじめとする
```

...  the guidelines starting with Policies A, B, ...

```
          ...  including / such as Policies A, B, ...
```

- ... guidelines, notably Policies A, B, ...
- ... guidelines, most notably Policies A, B, ...
- ... guidelines, the best examples being Policies A, B, ...
- ... guidelines[,] exemplified by Policies A, B, ...
- ... guidelines[,] whose list is headed by Policies A, B, ...

  ```
     Policies A, B, ... and other guidelines
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think they are all good and it is just good to have lots of possible options to use.

Answer (score 3):

How about: [*Starting with*](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%92%E3%81%AF%E3%81%98%E3%82%81%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) policy A and policy B....

Answer (score 0):

Think of と as an "assignment of value" particle.

Comment: Could you please provide more detail? What does "assignment of value" mean?

Answer (score -1):

はじめとする has the general meaning of "commencing/starting with" and is an irregular verb.

Comment: Do you mean はじめとする is a single verb?